# Arquitectura Android

Tags: java, android

Saludos, quiero iniciarme en el mundo de la programación android y quisiera saber si se puede programar entre capas en android, es decir, si puedo usar la capa de datos, negocio y presentación en android muchas gracias agradecería su colaboración

Comment: Te refieres al modelo vista-controlador ?

Comment: Mas o menos a eso me refiero, es decir me refiero a como se hace en un programa de escritorio, usando capa de datos, negocios, presentacion

Comment: Puedes usar cualquier metodología de trabajo, pero se recomienda que sea una metodología ágil

Comment: si, pero considero que la arquitectura entre capas puede formar parte de una metodología ágil, porque la metodología se basa mas en la interacion constante del cliente con el producto

Comment: si te sientes cómodo y la aplicas bien por que no ?

Comment: Ah ok, Gracias por la informacion

Comment: Ing. Jose, te saludo, el día de hoy es weekend pero en el [chat] puedes preguntar a otros expertos que pueden brindarte una valiosa opinión así como la de nuestro amigo Ashley (Felix). Saludos!.

Comment: Gracias, por la informacion me podren en contacto